# To what extent are "executors" considered "persecutors" (Rodeif)?

Tags: halacha, rodef

> "If two men get into a fight with each other, and the wife of one comes up to save her husband from his antagonist and puts out her hand and seizes him by his genitals, you shall cut off her hand; show no pity." [Deuteronomy.25.11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.25.11-12?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

Please forgive me if I'm interpreting this wrong, the woman sees her husband's attacker as a Rodeif and tries to stop him by hurting in his genital area. A person who sees the woman is commanded to attack the woman who attacks the attacker of her husband, because the woman is now considered a Rodeif.

I assume that if another person jumps in and tries to stop the woman by cutting her hand he is considered a Rodeif relative to the woman, et cetera.

To what extent are people on this list considered to be Roidef?